# Password not visibile in the input(works fine in chrome) not in firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a drop down checkbox for password validation.I've changed the background for the input on focusing it.But,The password is not displayed in the black color discs in the input even after specifying styles for it.Codes:

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

$("#Password").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
});

$("#Password").keyup(function() {
  var input = $(this).val();

  $("#oneCharacter").attr('checked', hasLetters(input));
  $("#oneNumber").attr('checked', hasNumbers(input));
  $("#strongPassword").attr('checked', isStrong(input));
});

var isStrong = function(input) {
  if (input.length > 8 && input.length < 16)
    return true;
};

var hasLetters = function(input) {
  return input.match(/[a-zA-Z]/);
};

var hasNumbers = function(input) {
  return input.match(/[0-9]/);
};

var hasSymbols = function(input) {
  return true;
};

var containsNoInvalidInput = function(input) {
  return true;
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 4%;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: inherit;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
  color: black;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  border: 2px solid #A0392F;
  background-color: #F7DDD8;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  padding-left: 40px;
  width: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-top: -10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-top: #B36F7A;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.squaredFour {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 9px;
      height: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 4px;
      left: 4px;
      border: 3px solid #333;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      background: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    &:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked+label:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left;">
    <span style="font-weight: 900;font-size: 25px;">New Password</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="password" id="Password" class="dropbtn">
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="strongPassword" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">8 - 16 characters long</label></div>
        <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="oneCharacter" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">At least one letter</label></div>
        <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="oneNumber" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">At least one number</label></div>
        <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="oneSymbol" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">At least one symbol</label></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">
      Confirm Password
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="password" id="" class="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: that is the expected output?

Comment: What do  you mean by visible? input type of password will obfuscate by default. Do you want the password to be readable?

Comment: Remove type="password" and use type="text" in the input tag of password.

Comment: When we type password,we will get discs in black color right, that one.

Comment: @envision, tried changing from type="password" to text its not working!

Comment: @HemaNandagopal The style has to be changed. You are targeting `input[type="password"]
{
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
  color:black;
}`
Changing it to `input[type="text"]
{
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
  color:black;
}`
will make it work.

Comment: Already did that too, Its not working.Can you post the working codes?

Comment: Guys, try in firefox not in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change input type to text if you want the password to be visible but if you want discs leave as `type="password"`.  The problem in firefox is because of the height you have set.  See the updated codesnippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 4%;
    }
    
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: auto;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      width: inherit;
      border: 2px solid;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    input[type="password"] {
      -webkit-text-security: disc;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover,
    .dropbtn:focus {
      border: 2px solid #A0392F;
      background-color: #F7DDD8;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      padding-left: 40px;
      width: inherit;
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 2px solid;
      margin-top: -10px;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 30px;
      border-top: #B36F7A;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
    
    .squaredFour {
      width: 20px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 20px auto;
      label {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: #fcfff4;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        &:after {
          content: '';
          width: 9px;
          height: 5px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 4px;
          left: 4px;
          border: 3px solid #333;
          border-top: none;
          border-right: none;
          background: transparent;
          opacity: 0;
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
        &:hover::after {
          opacity: 0.5;
        }
      }
      input[type=checkbox] {
        visibility: hidden;
        &:checked+label:after {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left;">
      <span style="font-weight: 900;font-size: 25px;">New Password</span>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="password" id="Password" class="dropbtn">
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="strongPassword" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">8 - 16 characters long</label></div>
          <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="oneCharacter" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">At least one letter</label></div>
          <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="oneNumber" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">At least one number</label></div>
          <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="oneSymbol" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">At least one symbol</label></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">
        Confirm Password
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="password" id="" class="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
          var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
              openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
          }
        }
      }

      $("#Password").click(function() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
      });

      $("#Password").keyup(function() {
        var input = $(this).val();

        $("#oneCharacter").attr('checked', hasLetters(input));
        $("#oneNumber").attr('checked', hasNumbers(input));
        $("#strongPassword").attr('checked', isStrong(input));
      });

      var isStrong = function(input) {
        if (input.length > 8 && input.length < 16)
          return true;
      };

      var hasLetters = function(input) {
        return input.match(/[a-zA-Z]/);
      };

      var hasNumbers = function(input) {
        return input.match(/[0-9]/);
      };

      var hasSymbols = function(input) {
        return true;
      };

      var containsNoInvalidInput = function(input) {
        return true;
      };
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please try in firefox, not chrome browser.

Comment: Problem in firefox is because of the height you have set.

Comment: That's great.Thank you so much :) Any idea why it was wokring in chrome alone?

Comment: No probs at all. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Each browser applies its own default CSS properties to HTML elements, which can sometimes result in unknown/unwanted behavior.  In this instance, I think chrome applies a different `box-sizing` attribute to input fields than firefox does... but don't quote me on this.

Comment: Yeah,got it :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the style as well.
Check the below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{
margin: 4%;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
  
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
 height: 60px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: inherit;
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 5px;


}
input[type="text"]
{
  color:black;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  border: 2px solid #A0392F;
  background-color:#F7DDD8;

  
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {

position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
padding-left: 40px;
width: inherit;
overflow: hidden;
border: 2px solid;
margin-top: -10px;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 30px;
border-top:#B36F7A;
}


.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.squaredFour {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 9px;
      height: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 4px;
      left: 4px;
      border: 3px solid #333;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      background: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    &:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }    
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left;">
<span style="font-weight: 900;font-size: 25px;">New Password</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" id="Password" class="dropbtn">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" >
<div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="strongPassword" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">8 - 16 characters long</label></div>
<div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="oneCharacter" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">At least one letter</label></div>
<div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="oneNumber" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">At least one number</label></div>
<div class="row" style="text-align:left;"> <input type="checkbox" id="oneSymbol" name="check" class="checkboxValid" /> <label for="squaredFour">At least one symbol</label></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">
Confirm Password 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="text" id="" class="">
</div>
</div>
<script>

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

$("#Password").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
});

$("#Password").keyup(function() {
  var input = $(this).val();
  
  $("#oneCharacter").attr('checked', hasLetters(input));
  $("#oneNumber").attr('checked', hasNumbers(input));
  $("#strongPassword").attr('checked', isStrong(input));
});

var isStrong = function(input){
    if(input.length > 8 && input.length < 16)
 return true;
};

var hasLetters = function(input){
    return input.match(/[a-zA-Z]/);
};

var hasNumbers = function(input){
    return input.match(/[0-9]/);
};

var hasSymbols = function(input){
    return true;
};

var containsNoInvalidInput = function(input){
    return true;
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try in the input field,are you able to see the disc in the input field?

Comment: You want to see the discs ?

Comment: Please open it in firefox.

Comment: It's because of `height: 0`, change it to something like `height: 50px` for firefox.